# graphql java - How to find out the root cause of "Invalid schema provided"?

Tags: java, schema, graphql, idl, graphql-java

How to find out the root cause of "Invalid schema provided"? I have many *.graphqls. Some of them just have data type IDL without any query and mutation definition.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource
>   [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory
>   method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.InvalidSchemaError: Invalid schema
>   provided (org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException) at:
>   [@313,1904:1904='[',<11>,120:12]

Comment: Unfortunately the error log isn't the greatest. Did you make any change that would break the parsing of your files recently?